# ASP MVC5 when I change something on my form and hit save, other data gets deleted

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When I change something on my dropDown from one Partial view and hit Save button, data gets deleted from another Partial view page, I'm using multiple data-toggle tabs, but the actual ActionLink stays. I'm trying obviously to keep the data from getting erased.

Any ideas/direction on why this may be happening?

DropDown from Partial document tab:

```
     <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DocumentType, new SelectList(ViewBag.DocumentTypes, "Value", "Text"), "Select Type", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Document Type" })
    </td>
```

SaveButton from view:

```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary saveDetails" disabled>Save Task Details</button>
```

Save And Set Details from Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAndSetDetails(TaskDetails taskDetails)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Id = SaveAll(taskDetails);
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = Id });
        }
```

Comment: Are both partials visible at the same time and are they in the same form? Are both drop-downs passing values to the taskDetails object?

Comment: @melkisadek yes both are visible at the same time and they are not on the same form, they are in multiple partial views. I just noticed that it can be anything (a drop-down, and/or updating notes, basically any kind of change) erases the data from the link, but yes both drop-downs are passing values to taskDetails object.

Comment: Have you debugged the taskDetails model that you're returning? My guess would be that you're passing null values into the model for the parts that you don't want to update and then EF is seeing these as changes which get applied when you save.

Comment: @melkisadek I actually just figured it out, in the controller, below ActionResult SaveAndSetDetails, I have the other SaveAll function to update items to the dataBase, there I had an object that I didn't need. My bad!